# Why do I have a huge number of 'concatenated strings' of the same html in my chrome dev tools memory tab

Tags: javascript, html, memory, google-chrome-devtools

I've just started using the 'Memory' tab within my Chrome Dev tools to try to understand my javascript app. The result is below.

I can see that I have 21384 'concatenated string' of the same HTML code from my app. Why is this? This code should only appear once on the page.

Is this saying that I've somehow stored this string in memory 21384 times?

[image: chrome dev tools memory link]

Comment: Are you sure it&#39;s the same same string, the retained sizes are different. It looks like the innerHTML of some element. Look for that in your code.

Comment: yes, It's a partial that I am grabbing through an post request. still no reason it should be logged so many times - I only grab it once.

Comment: are you modifying the string?

Comment: yes, there are various strings being inserted through loops, prior to embedding in the DOM

Comment: You have to give us your code, so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

It turned out this is something to do with how mustache.js caches files! I used `Mustache.clearCache();` to deal with this memory leak

This [article](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/661) provided some insight